# Program not doing update in ForEach Loop

Tags: php

I am trying to update a file OPPSHEDT with a priority and reason code. It seems the code gets stuck in the foreach loop. It gets to SQL with the Count I get the echo of the selstring on my browser then I do not get the echo of $Count and the update is not done. I'm not quite sure if I'm not connecting and doing the actual SQL on the Count or not. Is there anyway to tell what is going on here?

```
<?php   
require_once ('C:/wamp/db/login.php');

// Try to connect to database
try
{
$db = new PDO($db_hostname, $db_user, $db_pass);
}
catch (PDOExcepton $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (is_array($_POST['line'])) 
{ 
$ohord = $_POST['shedord'];
$ohbord = $_POST['shedbord'];
$date1 = $_POST['sheddat'];
$type = $_POST['shedtyp'];
$prty1 = $_POST['shedpty'];
$resn1 = $_POST['shedrsn']; 

foreach($_POST['line'] as $line_no)
{
$type1 = $type[$line_no]; 
$type2 = substr($type1, 0, 1);

$selstring = "Select Count(*) From LPCUSTTST.OPPSHEDT where sheddat = '$date1[$line_no]' and shedtyp = '$type2' and shedord = '$ohord[$line_no]' and shedbord =  '$ohbord[$line_no]'";
echo $selstring;
$s = $db->prepare("$selstring"); 
$s->execute();

echo $Count; 

if($Count > 0)
{
// Update data into detail
$selstring1 = "UPDATE LPCUSTTST.OPPSHEDT SET SHEDPTY = '$prty1[$line_no]', SHEDRSN = '$resn1[$line_no]' where sheddat = $date1[$line_no] and shedtyp = '$type2' and shedord = '$ohord[$line_no]' and shedbord = '$ohbord[$line_no]'";
echo $selstring1;
 $s = $db->prepare("$selstring1"); 
 $s->execute();
}
}
}
?>
```

Thank You

Comment: Do you have a `Tab` key?

Comment: Yes I have a Tab Key. What would that do?

Comment: i'm very new to php. This is the first set of insert and update programs I have written. What is a better way?

Comment: @MaryBethLeaf-Hamel It is much easier to read code when you use indentation to signify entering and exiting code blocks - e.g. when you enter a `foreach` loop, indent all the statements in it by one tab relative to the previous line. See [a snippet from a PHP style guide as an example](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#11-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first SQL statement contains `date1[$line_no]` while your second contains `$date1[$line_no]`.  You can make things much easier (and safer) by using parameterized queries instead.

**Edit:** You modified your post to include the missing dollar sign but my suggestion to use parameterized queries still stands.

```
$selstring = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total
              FROM LPCUSTTST.OPPSHEDT
              WHERE sheddat = :sheddat
              AND shedtyp   = :shedtyp
              AND shedord   = :shedord
              AND shedbord  = :shedbord';

$stm = $db->prepare($selstring); 
$stm->execute(
    array(
        'sheddat'  => $date1[$line_no],
        'shedtyp'  => $type2,
        'shedord'  => $ohord[$line_no],
        'shedbord' => $ohbord[$line_no]
    )
);
```

> I do not get the echo of $Count and the update is not done

In your code you do `echo $Count;` but `$Count` is never defined. You need to fetch the value (I added `total` to the above SQL):

```
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $row['total'];
```

Comment: Actually I do have them both the same. I made an error when spacing over the 4 spaces to get the code in here properly.

Comment: Please post actual code. Otherwise we can't properly analyze.

Comment: Instead of doing the prepare logic on the Select *Count SQL.  I did this and it worked fine. $s = $db->query("$selstring");
$Count = $s->fetchColumn();
echo $Count;

Comment: Thanks Everyone For All Your Help!!